# time complexity Java

Tags: java, time, time-complexity

The program counts maximum number of words in a sentence considering a text is given.A text can have multiple sentences. I have to find sentence with maximum words

I have the following code I need to optimize the time complexity for this 
it should not take more than 5 sec

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


class Solution {
    public int solution(String S) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8

        List<Integer> wca=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int wc,i;
        String[] sent=S.split("\\.+");

        while(sent.length!=0){

            for(i=0;i<sent.length;i++){
               wc=sent[i].split("\\s+").length; 
               wca.add(wc);
            }

        }

        Collections.sort(wca);

        return(wca.get(wca.size()-1));


    }
}
```

Comment: Without any knowledge of the input, there is no way to guarantee a running time. However, a sentence may end in characters other than a period.

Comment: What do you mean by 'count the maximum number of words'? ... as in the number of times each word appears? Or simply how many words are in the sentence?

Comment: Instead of adding the length of each sentence to a `List`, then sorting it and returning the largest, why not just have a `largest` variable that you compare to each size, and replace it if you find a bigger one.  That way you can eliminate the sorting step entirely. That takes you from O(n^2 * log(n)) to O(n) time.

Comment: You mean it shouldn't take more than 5 seconds to run or it shouldn't take more than five second to solve? BTW, there is no need to import `java.lang.*`, it's done implicitly.

Comment: You should really take @azurefrog's advice. This algorithm ca neasily be implemented in O(n) time.

Comment: FYI seconds is not a measure of time complexity.  `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);` has constant time complexity, which is the lowest that you can actually get, but it takes more than 5 seconds.

Comment: @azurefrog can you please give me the code for it

Comment: Avoid the split() method - it requires a lot of memory and needs to allocate a lot of objects. Use a RegEx expression (Pattern.compile() + Matcher.find()) to get the next entry.

Comment: I'm curious as to what causes the `while(sent.length!=0)` loop to stop running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to sort the list to simply find its largest value.  In fact you don't need a list at all.  Simply store the longest sentence as you go along.

```
public int findLongestSentence(String paragraph) {
    String[] sentences = paragraph.split("\\.|\\!|\\?");
    int maxSentenceLength = 0;

    for(String sentence : sentences) {
        String[] words = sentence.split("\\s");
        maxSentenceLength = Math.max(words.length, maxSentenceLength);
    }

    return maxSentenceLength;
}
```

This could be made more efficient by not using the `split()` method, but that would not affect the asymptotic time complexity.

P.S. Informative variable names are important, and along with good code formatting, made your code much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

> The program counts maximum number of words in a sentence

Suppose  you have this text:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

## Split by dot (.)

```
arr[0]= Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua

arr[1]= Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat

arr[2]= Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur

arr[3]= Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

## Amount of words is related with amount of spaces, so count the spaces will be easier.

int max = 0; // this hold the maximal space count
int index = 0; // this hold the index of the maximal space count

## Iterate over the array

```
   int spaces = arr[i].length - arr[i].replace(" ","").length;
    if(spaces>max){
         max = spaces;
         index = i;
    }
```

## At the end of that loop you will get the maximal amount of words and the index of the array of that sentence.

Comment: A text can have multiple sentences. I have to find sentence with maximum words

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want to parse an input text, so you can get the wordcount of each sentence and find the sentence witht the highest one.

First of all, you are only returning the highest wordcount, nothing to identify the sentence itself.

Second (as others have already pointed out) the sorting can be substituted with keeping only the longest sentence, and upon finding a longer one, replacing it. That would indeed bring it to O(n).

Third is the problem that sentences dont only end with periods.

```
  String longest;
for (String s : sentences){
 if(s.split(" ").length>longest.split(" ").length))
{
longest = s
}
}

return longest;
```